# Js file Syntax Error, Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Im REALLY new to javascript and i was following a tutorial/guide for it but when it came to Node.js and the command prompt, i got stuck. My file was called **"javascript.js"** instead of **"index.js"** and in the tutorial they typed in **$node index.js** which executed the code: *"Hello World"* since in the js file the code is `console.log("Hello World");`

For me, **Javascript.js** code is just simple:

```
// This is a test!
console.log("JavaScript");
```

But when i tried to execute my file into Node.js, it came out as:

```
> $node javascript.js
$node javascript.js
      ^^^^^^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'javascript'
>
```

The file path is correct and i fully installed Node.js yet i am still unsure what is causing this?

Comment: Are you typing this on your system terminal or within a Node terminal?  Whatever tutorial you're following may have been unclear on the two.

Comment: it works in the system terminal, but in the tutorial they used Node.js directly. But the tutorial seems outdated so im guessing thats one of the reasons.

Comment: what's a "node terminal"?

Comment: @GrafiCode: I may have confused the terminology myself.  I'm referring to the CLI when running `node` by itself, without supplying a file on the command line.  To be honest I've never actually used it, I've always put the code in a file and just executed that.

Answer (score 2):

You're in the **javascript console**, so all the content must be javascript code. You need to exit console with CTRL+D then run in terminal

```bash
node javascript.js
```